# Socket not working except when I connect the phone to the charger or pc using type-c cable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sockets

I made two android applications (host and client) that send data between them
Everything works very well, when I run them using android studio, while the cable is plugged to my physical device..
If I unplug the cable and run, some tasks related to java Socket can not be performed like sending some data to from server to client..
I am sure that my code has no problems because I tested all the tasks while cable is plugged in..
In addition, I know it's weird but when i plugged the charger, everything works !!
(My device is Huawei nova 7i)
Any solution ? Has anyone encountered this problem ?

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant code parts, especially, those that fail without USB cable.

Comment: There are many settings one of which might influence such behavior. Energy saving, USB tethering, ... No idea.